# Prove convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x(\sqrt x + 1)} dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> Prove the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x(\sqrt x + 1)} dx$

This was a question on an exam. I needed to prove that the above integral converges using the comparison test. I thought about using something along the lines of the integral of $1/(x^2+1)$ but I wasn't sure. I hope to learn from this so I can succeed on the final. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comparison is a good idea, but the expression you picked fails (as it is smaller than the actual expression and the integral associated with it converges).  Can you think of other possible comparisons?  It's often helpful to "decide" (well, guess, but with some confidence) whether you believe your integral converges or not.

Comment: using p test (when does the $\sum \frac1{n^p}$ converge?) , compare to $\frac1{x \sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{x}+1 \ge \sqrt{x}$ implies that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Thus, we have for $x>0$

$$\left|\frac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}+1)}\right|\le\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$$

Since $$\int_1^{\infty}x^{-3/2}dx=2$$

then by the comparison test, we conclude that

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(x^{1/2}+1)}\,\,\text{converges}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is convergent since $\frac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}+1)}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ when $x$ is large and $3/2>1$ so by the Riemann criterion we have $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ is convergent so we get the convergence of the integral   $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}+1)}.$